# Android Studio - Floating Action Button not working on ViewPager Initialization

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

### Please Help In Floating Action Button

I am trying to load the sharedFab(FloatingActionButton) with ViewPager. But it is not working when I load for first time (Before Page Change).

[image]

```
viewPagerMainAct.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0 :
                        sharedFab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_medical));
                        sharedFab.show();
                        sharedFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        sharedFab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sticky_notes));
                        sharedFab.show();
                        sharedFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sharedFab.hide();
                        break;
                    default:
                        sharedFab.hide();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: set the click listener outside the view pager, and when clicked, check the view pager current page.

Answer (score 1):

You use addOnPageChangeListener it wait for your request before do something. 
So, most easy way, it's just add this
sharedFab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_medical)) before viewPagerMainAct.

Second way it add picture in xml, like default picture. And then change it in changeListener.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line of code into the onCreate.

```
sharedFab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_medical));
                            sharedFab.show();
```

The first time you run the app, you don't put photos inside the button. But in the first click, this photo is placed

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that ur answers are correct but I am using a single FAB with two viewpager fragments and different work. And if it not loading at initialization then what we do?